# What is 1.999999 in 4 significant digit arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, numerical-calculus, significant-figures

Say you are doing some calculations in 4 significant digit arithmetic and at some point you get something like 1.9999999. You need to use this number in further calculations, also in 4 significant digit arithmetic. Do you use 2.000 or 1.999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2.000$$

When calculating to $n$ significant figures, first write down the first $n+1$ digits of the number, and then round the first $n$ digits based on the value of the $n+1$th.

So I would write down $1.9999$ and then note that the $9$ at the end implies I round up, giving $2.000$ to $4$sf.

Comment: Awesome, that came up in an exam and I didn't know so I just guessed randomly. I made the right guess. Thanks.